# gulp tasks .pipe() working

Tags: gulp, uglifyjs

Im learning gulp and i encountered a problem while executing gulp tasks .  [here](https://github.com/pavankumar0440/Gulp) is my working code. in the gulpfile default task is present where console is working but uglify() not creating the file in dist folder.

here is my output

```
$ gulp
[15:36:34] Using gulpfile c:\Users\VEERABABU\Desktop\check\GulpFile.js
[15:36:34] Starting 'default'...
its working here
[15:36:34] Finished 'default' after 18 ms...
```

please help me what im missing

Comment: https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/issues/800

Answer (score 0):

it might not be finding any js files to copy into dest.  I think the only one it could find right now is GulpFile.js, because your `gulp.src` search is pretty basic.

Why don't you try creating a folder with some js files (say, `public`), and try something like:

```
gulp.src('public/**/*.js').pipe(uglify()).pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

Note that the `**` means recursive through any number of directories.